# Jquery Datatable,Custom button,same row, next to select

Tags: jquery, button, datatable

I am using Jquery Datatable in my web application. I want to add custom button to the row which generating from datatable. [button should display in the are marked in red](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6UC4t.png)

Can anyone suggest some solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

Use DataTable's property as follows

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        dom: 'Bfrtip',
        buttons: [
            {
                text: 'My button',
                action: function ( e, dt, node, config ) {
                    alert( 'Button activated' );
                }
            }
        ]
    } );
} );
```